# How create thumbnail using ffmpeg on server?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, cpanel

I am trying to create thumbnail from video, i tried the following code to create thumbnail on xampp, and it works fine  but when try this on server it is not working.

```
$title ="xyz";
$ffmpeg = ".//ffmpeg//bin//ffmpeg";
$videofile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$thumbnail = ".//thumbnail//".$title.".jpg";
$size = "230x130";
$getfromsecond = 2;
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videofile -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size $thumbnail";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Is there any other way to create the to create thumbnail from ffmpeg on server?

Is there any way by which i can create thumbnail using ffmpeg without installing on cpanel, as i am not authorised for installing ffmpeg on cpnel?

Comment: Your webhost most likely has disabled `shell_exec()` and `exec()` and for a good reason.  If your script was compromised a hacker could potentially do anything on the server.

Comment: then what should i do for create thumbnail on cpanel

Comment: If you need to be able to run external programs from your website then maybe you should be considering a dedicated server which you administrate yourself. If you need additional PHP modules installed then try speaking with your webhost, they may be willing to add additional modules for you.

Answer (score 1):

As  a solution to your please try executing following code snippet

```
$title ="xyz";
$ffmpeg = ".//ffmpeg//bin//ffmpeg";
$videofile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$thumbnail = ".//thumbnail//".$title.".jpg";
$size = "230x130";
$getfromsecond = 2;
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videofile -y -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s $size $thumbnail";
 exec($cmd);
```